# Error after creating Android project using terminal with PhoneGap 2.2.0

Tags: cordova

I earlier had PhoneGap 2.0.0 working with Eclipse on my Mac. Last week, I downloaded the latest PhoneGap 2.2.0 and after following this link :
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android
I was able to generate the project folder using terminal, also in eclipse, pointed the project via New > Project > Android Project from Existing Code

But my however I get the following error:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/mzvr8

Could anyone please help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows you are using Android 2.2 which is rather old. You can install newer versions by launching the Android SDK Manager. Then select the newer version in the project's properties. See http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html